# Compatible connection over a riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

How do I prove the following assertion:

Let $\nabla$ be a connection on a riemannian manifold, then $\nabla$ is compatible with the metric if and only if for all $X,Y,Z\in \mathfrak{X}(M)=\Gamma(TM)$ we have:

$X\langle Y,Z \rangle = \langle\nabla_XY,Z\rangle+\langle Y,\nabla_XZ\rangle$

Comment: What's your definition of "compatibility"?

Comment: For every $X,Y$ parallel vector fields along a curve we have: $\langle X,Y \rangle$ = constant, but suppose you know that the product rule can be applied to $\frac{d\langle X,Y \rangle}{dt}$

Comment: $\frac{d\langle X,Y \rangle}{dt}=\langle \frac{DX}{dt},Y\rangle + \langle X,\frac{DY}{dt}\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Proposition 3.2 and Corollary 3.3](http://books.google.ca/books?id=ct91XCWkWEUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: actualy I was trying to understand that corollary but stuck, but after some time I understand :)

Comment: Dear Jr. Knowing what have tried out precisely, would be helpful to those who want to answer your questions.

Comment: Do Carmo says at the beginning of the proof of Proposition 3.2: "It is obvious that the equation $$\frac d{dt} \langle X,Y \rangle = \langle \frac{DX}{dt},Y\rangle+\langle X,\frac{DY}{dt}\rangle, \quad t\in I$$ implies that $\nabla$ is compatible with $\langle \, , \, \rangle$." How exactly does this equation imply that $\frac d{dt}\langle X,Y\rangle=0$, so that the desired conclusion follows? (I'm self-studying this topic right now.)